# Android - Sharepoint Server Application communication

Tags: android, sql, http, sharepoint-2013

I searched for this everywhere and I can't find an answer.

I am trying to make an Android app that uses Microsoft Sharepoint Server 2013 for authentification then for some data exchange. Is it possible through HTTP request/response? Or this is possible some other way? I need at least a hint on how I can access the database on the server, send some information and insert it there (for example). Any ideas? Thanks

Comment: where does the Azure fit in this scenario?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access the SharePoint object model via a RESTful service from an Android/Java app. The REST service is called client.svc and you can use OData for CRUDQ operations. You access the service bu using the _api shortcut --> `http://server/site/_api/lists/getbytitle('listname')`

More info here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/fp142380.aspx.